# Bash: remove substrings using ${string//substr/rep}

Tags: string, bash, substring

I am trying to write a small shell script, which can read a text file (given as argument), deleting all invalid Base64 chars and then decode this Base64 String into readable Text.

For this Example i can assume, that i have got a valid Base64 String polluted with additional invalid chars. So simply deleting them makes the String valid again.

I am having problems with the "remove al invalid chars" part.

Here is my Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")
#echo ${args[0]}

# read file
STRING="$(cat ${args[0]})"
echo "Input:"
echo $STRING
echo "\n"

#BASE64_REGEX='!/[^A-Za-z0-9+\/=]/'
STRING=${STRING//[!?_-]/}
echo "Fixed:"
echo $STRING
echo "\n"

# decode String
DECODED=$(base64 -d <<< "$STRING")
echo "Decoded:"
echo $DECODED
echo "\n"
```

I think my problem is this part here `STRING=${STRING//[!?_-]/}`. After this Operation the String contains `??___---` + linebreak, so i must somehow be close.

**EDIT:**
This would be the example String. And i try to remove all Characters, which are *NOT* part of the Base64 alphapet.

```
!RGllIGVpbnppZ2VuIFNvbmRlc??nplaWNoZW4gaW0gQmFzZTY0IEFscGhhYmV0IHNpbmQgIisg_L_y_A9Ii4gQWxsZSB3ZWl0ZXJlbi-B-T-b25kZXJ6!ZWljaGVuICIhIsKnJCUiIGtvbW1!lbiBkb3J0IG5pY2h0IHZvci"4=
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you give us the actual string and what you want to replace it with? This information is not helping. What are your file contents?

Comment: What do you want to remove here?

Comment: I added the missing infos. Sorry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It' because `!` in first position in a character set invert the set like `^` (note: only true for pattern matching (glob) not regex matching, but in this case it's just pattern matching)
maybe you want

```
STRING=${STRING//[?\!_-]/}
```

why not use the set in comments

```
STRING=${STRING//[^A-Za-z0-9+\/=]/}
```

Comment: You are totally right. Thank you very much. I would never have spotted this.

Comment: Could you, please, explain why and how this works. I just found the resp. section in my `man bash` but I don't understand how this co-incides with your solution. (Sorry, I'm a little bit confused but willing to learn.)

Comment: @Scheff: `!` has a special meaning in `bash` to return the previous command, it needs to be escaped by a leading `\` before it.

Comment: Thanks, but I still didn't get the whole. According to my `man bash`, replacement is `${parameter/pattern/string}`. Thus, it starts to confuse me from `${STRING//` which I consider to replacement of empty string. Is this something new what's not yet supported in my bash? (I have 4.4.12(3).)

Comment: yes the `!` is escaped because in interactive mode (command line) bash is a reference to a command line entry see `Event designators` in `man bash`, otherwise `Pattern matching` `[...]` : `If  the  first character following the [ is a !  or a ^ then any character not enclosed is matched.`

Comment: @Scheff: the difference between `${parameter/pattern/string}` and `${parameter//pattern/string}` is that the latter replaces all the occurences of the `pattern` and the former does once

Comment: @Scheff: `${parameter/pattern/string} Pattern substitution.  ... If  pattern  begins with /, all matches of pattern are replaced with  string.`